# Using Perl SFTP, I keep getting an fsetstat error when I PUT a file

Tags: perl, sftp

Trying to SFTP a file to a remote server, the file gets copied over but returns an error.

```
use Net::SFTP;

...

my $sftp = Net::SFTP->new($host, %args);
$sftp->put("testfile.txt", "testfile.txt.bak");
```

Gives the following error:
list.pl: Couldn't fsetstat: Failure at list.pl line 182

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;
...

my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host, %args);
$sftp->put("testfile.txt", "testfile.txt.bak",
            copy_time => 0, copy_perm => 0);
```

Comment: At least add some info to the solution like this:
https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign#Put-method-fails-even-with-late_set_perm-set